# Limit of a subsequence of $x_n$ where $x_n(x_n -1) \rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

From a recent past paper i was attempting i found this in the answers. I had answered that the statement was false however the answer disagrees. There was no earlier parts of the question or extra info other than the top line given.

> Suppose there is some sequence $(x_n)_ {n=1}^{\infty}, n \in \mathbb N$ which satisfies $x_n(x_n - 1) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

> It is true that there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k} \rightarrow 1$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$

I thought that $x_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$ would be a valid counterexample as there are no $x_{n_k} \rightarrow 1$ and the sequence itself satisfies the original equation, i.e

$\frac{1}{n+1}(\frac{1}{n+1} -1) = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} - \frac{1}{1+n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: You can even simply take $x_n=0$. My assumption would be that you actually did miss some additional information, or that some part of the problem was missing due to the editorial process.